# Creating dataset object using child class of custom class

Tags: java, apache-spark

Consider a class called Person.
We can create a dataset for it like
Dataset dateset = sqlContext.createDataset(list, Encoders.bean(Person.class));

The syntax above is not completely correct but I am taking just an example

Now I want to refer tot he structure of a child class of Person while creating this dataset. how can that be done?

Comment: You've created a dataset of type `person`. So you can only refer to the Dataset as `Dataset<Person>`, both at compile time and run-time. You cannot use the child class to refer to it after creation.

Comment: I want to refer to structure of child class while creating the dataset. Dataset of Person should have structure of it's child classes also when creating it. I want to know how we can achive that

Comment: I don't believe you can do that. Only a parent can replace a child class without a compile time or run-time error. Not the other way around. If your child class has a member variable that is not in the parent, it would throw a class cast exception.